# NDSolve Convergence Issue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to use NDSolve to solve r[u] equation below. 
The problem seems like the slow convergence. I have searched some questions regarding this kind of problem. I think many people answered in some form of increasing working precision. If I increase the workingprecision, i get that the argument is not upto the machine precision. I will attach the warning it gave when I do NDSolve and my code.

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one 
of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly 
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 
18 recursive bisections in s near {t,s} = {4.85075,0.0000644015}. NIntegrate 
obtained 5.58828*10^-21-7.99344*10^-27 I and 2.9124298522935253`*^-24 for 
the integral and error estimates.
```

Code:

```
L[u_] := 1/(64 \[Pi]^2 t^5 Sqrt[u]) (-4 I t (s + I t^2 + s Log[4]) + (s^2 + 
4 I s t - 4 t^2 + t^4) Log[-2 + (I s)/t + t] - (s^2 - 4 I s t - 4 t^2 + t^4) 
Log[2 + (I s)/t + t])

H[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[t^2*u^(5/2)/2*(Log[1 - L[u]] + L[u]/(1 - 
L[u])), {t, 0, 10^3}, {s, -10^3, 10^3}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 
8,WorkingPrecision -> 12]

Plot[H[u], {u, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]

sol = NDSolve[{H[u] == u*r'[u] - 2 r[u], r[10^6] == -1}, r, {u, 
10^-9, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 12]

Plot[Evaluate[r[u] /. sol], {u, 10^-9, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> 
Green]
```

Where on the NDSolve line, I wanted a boundary condition that $r\rightarrow -1$ as $u\rightarrow\infty$, but just set u=10^6 to avoid infinity expression; I hope that's okay.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much for reading my question!

Comment: The errors are from `NIntegrate`, not `NDSolve`.  Also, I suggest you delete `WorkingPrecision -> 12`.

Comment: But when I just do up to plotting the NIntegrate part, I did get a graph with Only Warning that the integral is converging slowly. Not that it failed to converge. So I assume there must be something with the NDSolve. All the bad warnings pop up after NDSolve command... is there anything I can do? Thanks.

Comment: Note: Above warning lines in the original post are for when I removed WorkingPrecision->12. When I put it in as the code That I wrote up there, it takes forever to run on my computer (cheap computer, possibly). I am a beginner in mathmatica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started as an extended comment but has morphed into an answer.

```
H[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[t^2*u^(5/2)/2*(Log[1 - L[u]] + L[u]/(1 - L[u])), 
    {t, 0, 10^3}, {s, -10^3, 10^3}]
Table[H[u]/u^3 /. u -> 10^i, {i, 6}]
(* {414.781, 56.4169, 7.66857, 0.893855, 0.141469, 0.0192026} *)
```

plus the first warning message given in the question.  Increasing `WorkingPrecision` yields

```
H[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[t^2*u^(5/2)/2*(Log[1 - L[u]] + L[u]/(1 - L[u])), 
    {t, 0, 10^3}, {s, -10^3, 10^3}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Chop
(* {414.780936186193432754748625707, 56.4169472731001172506090076002, 
    7.66856870136135201710072009702, 1.041808172243427818769297282494, 
    0.141469419050140253351266614811, 0.0192025581519389795391545651320} *)
```

plus both the first and second warning messages in the question.  Nonetheless, the two sets of answers are in good agreement, suggesting that they are correct to several significant figures.  Incidentally, `Chop` has deleted imaginary parts of order `10^-15`.  Although the integrand as written is complex, it is possible to rewrite the integral symbolically to make the integrand real, although the resulting expression is impractically large.

Next, the ODE can be solved symbolically in terms of `H`.

```
Clear[H]
Flatten@DSolve[H[u] == u*r'[u] - 2 r[u], r[u], u]
(* {r[u] -> u^2*C[1] + u^2*Integrate[H[K[1]]/K[1]^3, {K[1], 1, u}]} *)
```

Thus, for `r[u]` to approach `-1` as `u` approaches infinity, the integral must approach `C[1] - 1/u^2`.  However, from the sample evaluations of `H[u]` above, it is clear that `H[u]` itself approaches `0` more slowly than `1/u`.  Therefore, the integral blows up as `u` approaches infinity.  So, the boundary condition sought in the question cannot be achieved.

**Addendum - Behavior of `H[u]` near `u == 0`.**

Experimentation suggests that the double integral defining `H[u]` behaves a bit better at small `u` with options, `Exclusions -> {0, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 12`.  Then, `H[u]/u^3` scales roughly as `u^(-6/7}`, as can be seen from

```
LogLogPlot[H[u]/u^3, {u, 10^-15, 10^-1}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {u, H}, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

The integral can, then, be performed without error messages (as requested by the OP in a comment below).

```
NIntegrate[H[u]/u^3, {u, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12]
(* 21636.9 *)
```

For completeness, `H` (not `H/u^3`) is given by

```
Plot[H[u], {u, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {u, H}, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

**Second Addendum**

A numerical solution can be obtained directly by substituting `r[u] = u^2 w[u]`, as suggested by the symbolic solution above.  The ODE becomes

```
(Unevaluated[H[u] == u*D[r[u], u] - 2 r[u]] /. r[u] -> u^2 w[u]) // Simplify
(* H[u] == u^3 Derivative[1][w][u] *)
```

As already noted above, `r[10^6] == -1` is not a valid proxy for `r[Infinity] == -1`.  So, arbitrarily choose `w[1] == 1`.  Then, `r[u]` is given by

```
sol = u^2 w[u] /. Flatten@NDSolve[{w'[u] == H[u]/u^3, w[1] == 1}, w, {u, 10^-6, 2}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
```

plus `C[1] u^2` as obtained symbolically earlier.

```
Plot[sol, {u, 10^-6, 2}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {u, r}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've got a clue. It's kinda a different question, suppose I discard the u^2C[1] term, then i tried to NIntegrate H / u^3 term let's say 10^-9 to 100 (to avoid singularity at 0) it doesn't work too well. Do you know how to deal with this situation? I was expecting a convergent integral near 0 since H/u^3 decay slower than 1/u.

Comment: @DukeSmith  So that I am sure I understand, you would like to integrate `H[u]/u^3` from zero to 100.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. u^2 * Integrate H[u]/u^3   Thank you for fast replies!

Comment: @DukeSmith  I do not have a quick answer for you now but will see what I can do tomorrow.

Comment: I followed your options for H[u], but I still get NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in u near {u} = {5.27879*10^-7}. NIntegrate obtained 1973.3583278644496` and 3.302641685197459` for the integral and error estimates. when I try to integrate for H[u]/u^3. Not sure how you did it.

Comment: I used    r[q_?NumericQ] := q^2*NIntegrate[H[u]/u^3, {u, 0, q}]
Plot[r[q], {q, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Green]   (Tried to plot $u^2\int_0^udq \frac{H(q)}{q^3}$)

Comment: @DukeSmith  Use `r[q_?NumericQ] := q^2*NIntegrate[H[u]/u^3, {u, 0, q}, MaxRecursion -> 12]`, but it is slow.  For instance, r[.001] // AbsoluteTiming` returns `{60.3514, 0.00794626}`!  I have not tried to generate the whole plot, although I could.  Alternatively, ask for less precision from the integration.  Incidentally, I changed a few parameters in my answer to reduce the occurrence of warning messages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. this is great. I was very disappointed for the computing time of the original code, But the second addendum computes much much more quickly than the original code! And I did confirm that they produce identical result. Do you know why? Just brilliant

Comment: @DukeSmith  The last formulation solves the same equations as the earlier ones, just more efficiently.  If I had though of it earlier, it would have save us both a lot of time.  Too bad.